# How to get delta table columns details (nullable, lenth, constraints etc) in java using spark thrift jdbc?

Tags: jdbc, hive, delta-lake

I am a new bee to Delta lake -
Created a delta table using below statement :
create table schema_test.test_delta_table (userId integer NOT NULL,title String) using delta;
I am tryin to access delta table via JDBC (using Spark Thrift Server), and when I try to execute below code (using hive-jdbc jar)
It gives empty result. Any idea on this ?
DatabaseMetaData dmd = con.getMetaData();
ResultSet colrs = dmd.getColumns(null, "schema_test", "test_delta_table", "%");
At the same time if I create the table like below (without USING DELTA), above 2 lines of code works fine
create table schema_test.test_delta_table (userId integer NOT NULL,title String)
Any suggestion would be much appreciated
Thanks